# inequalities for optimization over psd matrices with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Consider two p.s.d. matrices $A$ and $B$ both in $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$. Define $$a = argmax_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} x^\top A x $$ and $$b = argmax_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} x^\top B x $$ both subjected to $x \in \{x: \|x\|_1 \leq s ~{and}~ \|x\|_2 =1\}$ where $\|.\|_1$ and $\|.\|_2$ are the standard $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ vector norms respectively.

I was wondering if one can prove the following:

$$1-(a^\top b)^2 \leq C \|A-B\|_{\infty}$$ 
where $\|.\|_{\infty} = \max_{i,j} (A_{i,j}-B_{i,j})$ for some constant $C$ (exact expression of $C$ would be appreciated).

Answer (score 1):

Is $\|x\|_{\ell^0}$ the number of non-zeros in $x$?

Then, this estimate will not hold:
Take $\varepsilon > 0$, $A = \mathrm{diag}(1,1+\varepsilon)$, $B = \mathrm{diag}(1+\varepsilon,1)$, $s = 1$.
Then, $a = (0,1)$, $b = (1,0)$ and hence your estimate becomes
$$1 \le C \, \varepsilon.$$

Comment: gerw, Sorry for edit now, I meant $\|\|_1$ , the $\ell_1$ norm.

Comment: @kk02: No problem, the argument should still remain valid ;)